# Retrieve number of citations of a scientific paper in a given year

Tags: cross-reference, bibliography, citations, google-scholar, scopus

How can I retrieve the number of citations of a paper in a given year?

I had a look at Scopus Citation Overview API but the [pybliometrics documentation](https://pybliometrics.readthedocs.io/en/stable/classes/CitationOverview.html) says the API key needs to be approved by Elsevier for this purpose, and in fact it is returning error 403.

Are there other data sources from which I can retrieve the number of citations?

The [rcrossref](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rcrossref/rcrossref.pdf) package provides a function `cr_citation_count` which seems to get the number of citation *today*.

I need the number of citation at a given year (for instance, if a paper was published in 2010, I may need the number of citation in 2015, not as of today at 2021).

Comment: @anpami thank you, can you put that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First, access the [OpenCitations API](https://opencitations.net/index/coci/api/v1#/citations/%7Bdoi%7D) with a given DOI.
- Second, fetch the DOIs of all the citing papers.
- Third, use these newly fetched DOIs and loop them through the [CrossRef API](https://github.com/CrossRef/rest-api-doc) to obtain the respective publication dates.

**Example**:

- You are interested in obtaining all citations from the year 2020 to the paper with the DOI [10.1080/17512786.2019.1682940](https://doi.org/10.1080/17512786.2019.1682940).
- First, access *OpenCitations* via https://opencitations.net/index/coci/api/v1/citations/10.1080/17512786.2019.1682940 (which finds 6 citations in total).
- Second, fetch the values in the field `citing` -- they show the DOIs of the citing papers. For example, the second `citing` DOI is `10.17645/mac.v8i3.3019`.
- Third, access CrossRef with the help of these DOIs, such as via https://api.crossref.org/works/10.17645/mac.v8i3.3019, and look at the `published`-field (which is `2020-07-10`).  Keep only those values that start with the year `2020`.
- Note - - maybe you could omit the third step if you fetch the `creation`-field in OpenCitations during the second step (it seems to be identical to the `published`-field in CrossRef). I haven't tested that systematically.

Be aware that the citation counts between OpenCitations and CrossRef can vary (OpenCitaions usually shows less citations than CrossRef).

Comment: I ended up asking Scopus for permission, but thank you very much!